# WPF Textbox Time format (not hundred hours)

Tags: wpf, binding, textbox

I got here

```
    <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="SessionTimeColumnTextBox 
        Binding="{Binding TreatmentTime, StringFormat=HH:mm}" 
        Visibility="Visible"
    />
```

but it shows hundred hours such as 17:32 instead of 5:32PM, how can I reformat the time into not hundred hours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong format. `HH` means 24 hours format. Use `hh` for 12 hours format and `tt` for AM/PM designator.

```
StringFormat=hh:mmtt
```

Refer [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)